# opencart .htaccess force https and htpassword

Tags: .htaccess, opencart2.x, .htpasswd

**Goal**

1. My goals is want to redirect all http traffic to https with www. prefix
2. I want to add htpasswd in my admin directory.(https)

**Current problem**

When I access to
`https://www.myshop.com/my/admin` it prompt for Basic Authenticate. When I input correctly, it redirect to `http://www.myshop.com/my/admin` and prompt again the Basic Authenticate, I need to type again then I only redirect back to `https://www.myshop.com/my/admin` then show me the login page.

Below is my code, which part I did wrong, or what is the best solution to do it?

my opencart put in a folder of country name .eg `/my` for malaysia
in my root file, I have opencart .htaccess

my vhost is set under 
`/var/www/html/opencart2/`

all my development files are here.
`/var/www/html/opencart2/my/`

my .htaccess
`/var/www/html/opencart2/my/.htaccess`

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /my/
#force run https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myshop.com$
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myshop.com/my/$1 [R=301,L]

#AWS EB REDIRECT to https
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
#NEW REWRITE RULES
RewriteRule    ^contact/?$    index.php?route=information/contact  [L]  #Contact Page
#END NEW REWRITE RULES
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

under my admin folder .htaccess `/var/www/html/opencart2/my/admin/.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Admin Area"
AuthUserFile /usr/share/apache/secret/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I create a similar environment for this case
https://opencart.webhop.me/my/admin/

username: admin
password: admin

As you login u see it will prompt two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If admin login form is submitting to http:// you probably need to update admin/config.php constant `HTTPS_SERVER` and make sure it has https:// in the url.  Also make sure you have **"Use SSL"** set to **"yes**" in your admin settings.

Comment: in config file, I had set all the SSL. now I want .htaccess to help me do auto redirect and the real issue is 2 times redirect for .htpasswd. It is not able how to config the SSL in opencart.

Comment: I understand but submitting the form shouldn't be taking you to http.  What is the value of the form `action` attribute for admin login?

Comment: ok, finally I able to generate a case study for this situation. kindly login to https://opencart.webhop.me/my/admin/ , i edit more info on my questions

Comment: I edit more info on my questions for the authentication info. As you tried, it required two times authentication.

Comment: You never answered my question above.  Anyway, I've had a look and it's as I've said before, you don't have SSL configured properly.   Check the value of HTTPS_SERVER and the Use SSL setting.  Your form is submitting to http which is wrong and indicates your configuration file is not set up to support SSL.  It's further evidenced by the abundance of errors and missing resources when the page loads since your url base is http on an https page.